# Expansion of $f(z)=\frac{z}{e^{z}-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I would like someone to help me writing $f(z)$ as a sum $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} c_n z^n$ at the point $z_0=0$.

My attempt:

$$f(z)= \frac{z}{e^{z}-1} = \frac{-z}{1-e^z} =-z(1 + e^z + e^{2z} + ...) \\ = -z\bigg(1 + \bigg(1+z + \frac{z^2}{2!}+...\bigg) + \bigg(1+2z + \frac{2z^2}{2!}+...\bigg) +  ...\bigg) $$

However this would imply that $c_1=-\infty\ldots $

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: Bernoulli numbers!

Comment: What you *are* missing is that the geometric series $\frac{1}{1-w} =1+w+w^2+\cdots$ works for $|w|<1$. You cannot use it with $w=e^z$ near the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the function $f:\begin{cases} \Omega\subseteq \mathbb{C} &\longrightarrow \mathbb{C},\\z&\longmapsto \frac{z}{e^{z}-1}\end{cases}$, we need to write $\displaystyle f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}a_{j}z^{j}$ around $z_{0}=0$.

We know that $\displaystyle z\mapsto e^{z}=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{j}}{j!}$ around $z_{0}=0$. Then $\displaystyle \frac{z}{e^{z}-1}=\frac{1}{1+\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{(j+1)!}}=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} {\rm B}_{n}\frac{z^{n}}{n!}$ around $z_{0}=0$ where the sequence $({\rm B}_{n})_{n\geqslant 0}$ [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to obtain some explicit expression for the $B_n$'s?

Comment: You're welcome. A explicit form for Bernoulli numbers $(B_{n})_{n}$ not, see the link we know as generating the Bernoulli numbers. Then you can find some terms of your expansion for $f(z)$, for example: $$\frac{z}{e^{z}-1}=1-\frac{1}{2}z+\frac{1}{6}\frac{z^{2}}{2!}-\frac{1}{30}\frac{z^4}{4!}+\frac{1}{42}\frac{z^{6}}{6!}-\frac{1}{30}\frac{z^{8}}{8!}+\cdots.$$